# Explanation of the following algorithm to find nCr modulo P

Tags: algorithm, factorial, number-theory

I was trying to solve a problem involving large factorials modulo a prime, and found the following algorithm in another's solution:

```
long long factMod (long long n, long long p)
{
    long long ans = 1;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        long long cur = 1;

        for (long long i = 1; i < p; i++)
        {
            cur = (cur * i) % p;
        }

        ans = (ans * modPow(cur, n/p, p)) % p;


        for (long long i = 1; i <= n % p; i++)
        {
            ans = (ans * i) % p;
        }

        n /= p;
    }

    return (ans % p);
}

long long nChooseK(long long n, long long k, long long p)
{
    int num_degree = get_degree(n, p) - get_degree(n - k, p);
    int den_degree = get_degree(k, p);
    if (num_degree > den_degree) { return 0; }

    long long nFact = factMod(n, p);
    long long kFact = factMod(k, p);
    long long nMinusKFact = factMod(n-k, p);

    long long ans = (((nFact * modPow(kFact, p - 2, p)) % p) * modPow(nMinusKFact, p - 2, p))%p;
    return ans;
}
```

I know the basics of number theory but can't seem to figure out how this works.

The nChooseK function appears to use the definition of combination [n!/(n-k)!k!] with the modular inverse computed using Fermat's little theorem to replace the division. However, according to one of the answers, the factMod function does not actually compute the factorial. If this is the case, how does the nChooseK function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, n! ≡ 0 mod p if and only if n ≥ p, but `factMod` isn't computing n! mod p – it's computing n!/p<sup>k</sup> mod p where k is the exponent of p in the prime factorization of n!, <strike>perhaps</strike> for the purpose of computing a binomial coefficient. Iteration i (counting from 0) of the loop counts the contribution of those factors 1…n whose prime factorization includes p<sup>i</sup>. The statement `n /= p;` yields the subproblem on the multiples of p.

The function `get_degree(n, p)` presumably returns the exponent of p in the prime factorization of n!. If `get_degree(n, p) == get_degree(k, p) + get_degree(n - k, p)`, then the factors of p in numerator and denominator exactly cancel, and we can use `factMod` to account for the other factors. Otherwise, the number of combinations is divisible by p, so we return 0.

Since (p-1)! ≡ -1 mod p by [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), the first inner loop is redundant.

Comment: It seems to work for all values I tried though. Could you provide any insight as to how the algorithm works?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The function is part of a larger program to compute nCk % p. I have included the choose function in my opening post. If `factMod` does not in fact compute `n! % p`, then how does the function `nChooseK` work?

Comment: @user2612743 It cancels the factors of p before modding out. See my edit.

Comment: Within the factMod function, what does the step `ans = (ans * modPow(cur, n/p, p)) % p;` do?

Comment: @user2612743 It multiplies `ans` by the p-nondivisible numbers between `1` and `n - n%p`. The second inner loop multiplies `ans` by the p-nondivisible numbers between `n - n%p` and `n`.